# writing text into the div using document.write

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add text to two DIVS with ids= DIV1 and DIV2 in a html page(home.html) from a js page main.js using document.write() command. On clicking the button in html page, the respective text must appear in the hmtl page.

The code is as given below. I keep getting an error: document.write can be a form of eval. Is there a possible way of using document.write() and print the text in the div sections.

HTML code:

```
<head>
  <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="button" value="click!" onclick="xyz()">
  </form>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT code:

```
function xyz(){
  var arr={name:"abc",school:"pqrst"};
  document.write('<div id="div1">'+"Name:"+ arr.name +'</div>');
  document.write('<div id="div2">'+"School:"+ arr.school +'</div>');
}
```

Name:abc
School:pqrst

Comment: @ellipsis — Only for values of fine which depend on specific input which doesn't result in JS being evaluated … i.e. which the message the question is asking about is warning about.

Answer (score 2):

> ...using document.write() command

Don't. Only use `document.write` during the initial parsing of the page, or to write to a new window you've just opened (or better yet, don't use it at all).

Instead, use the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model). Example:

```js
function xyz(){
    var arr = {name: "abc", school: "pqrst"};
    addDiv("name", "Name:" + arr.name);
    addDiv("age", "School:" + arr.school);
}
function addDiv(id, content) {
    var d = document.createElement("div");
    d.id = id;
    d.textContent = content;
    document.body.appendChild(d);
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="click!" onclick="xyz()">
```

If you have an HTML string you want to insert, you can do that with [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), but beware of combining text from an object with HTML, because any `<` or `&` in the text must be escaped correctly (more than that if you're going to put the content into an attribute, as with your `id` values). It happens that your two example values don't have those characters, but you can't assume that in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insertAdjacentHTML()` in place of `document.write()`. Refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) for more details

```js
function xyz(){
var arr={name:"abc",school:"pqrst"};
document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div id="name">'+"Name:"+ arr.name +'</div>');
document.querySelector('body').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div id="age">'+"School:"+ arr.school +'</div>');
}
```

```html
<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="click!" onclick="xyz()">
</form>
```